# Not receiving any emails from my Django project to reset user password

Tags: python, django

Django Version: 2.1

**Problem**: I am currently make a blog with Django and I am working on a feature which allows user to reset their password by sending the users email through. However I am not able to receive/send any emails through my PasswordResetView. What did I do wrong?

**Things I've tried:**
I have already set "Allow less secure apps: ON" in my google account.
I tried looking everywhere on Google and the answers provided are mostly asking me to try to Allow less secure apps on Google. It's been 24H I can't seem to find what have I done wrong..

I also tried using the EmailMessage class at my views.py. I am able to send email to myself. I don't think there is any issue with the authentication of my email.

Thanks in advance!

**settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'pwpcp@sy66r-ve4(o1o3_a3+2g6(zj)lp1g^q($mspw(kr6q$o'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'user.apps.UserConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_blog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'     # go to crispy documentation online

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-index'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword1234'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from user import views as user_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='user/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='user/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('password-reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name='user/password_reset.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='user/password_reset_done.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
             template_name='user/password_reset_confirm.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
             template_name='user/password_reset_complete.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:      # only add this in when debug mode is on
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: please share the error,

Comment: While there could be a long answer explaining the limitations of Google Mail, the short answer is: use an other mail service or your own mail server.

Comment: There are no error messages. I tried sending an email through the EmailMessage class and it worked (I am able to receive email from that Class from Django).

Comment: I found the issue. It seems like I need to make sure that the email is registered in the database in order to reset my user password. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

make sure mention your apps on top of your installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
'user.apps.UserConfig',

'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

'crispy_forms',
]
```